# Can I disable Apples ssh server entirely, and install openssh-server?

Tags: macos, openssh

After recent changes in high sierra to the way /etc/ssh/sshd_config I'd like to investigate ditching the macOS Sharing ssh, and put my own one in. Similar to doing apt-get install openssh-server on linux. I prefer to change my ports, authentication options, tunneling, banner and motd settings the old way, by editing sshd_config and restarting the server manually. I want to be able to connect from my linux box to my mac like I used to with ssh.

eg:

```
brew install openssh-server
```